# `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode` only when using FrontiersinHarvard style

Tags: floats, subfloats, harvard-style

I want to submit an manuscript to an journal that provides a template there: [https://www.frontiersin.org/about/author-guideline](https://www.frontiersin.org/about/author-guidelines) however is does seem to accept easily subfigures. The error disappears if I select elsarticle format (by removing th comment on the first line) and unselect the FrontiersinHarvard format (by commenting out the second line) What should I do?

```
%\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[utf8]{FrontiersinHarvard} % for articles in journals using the Harvard Referencing Style (Author-Date), for Frontiers Reference Styles by Journal: https://zendesk.frontiersin.org/hc/en-us/articles/360017860337-Frontiers-Reference-Styles-by-Journal
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url,caption, graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}


\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
        bottom=20mm
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That document class contains a different, incompatible definition of the `subfigure` environment. The sample document says "If you are submitting a figure with subfigures please combine these into one image file with part labels integrated." And the guide says "Cite figures with subfigures as figure \ref{fig:2}B." Can you do that?

Comment: Indeed @frabjous many thanks. Looking at the big picture: it's really diffcult to prepare a nice layout for a manuscript and spending time refining only to discover afterward that the layout you spent so much energy on, is not accepted by the journal you are submitting to. I really don't know what is the right balance. Do you have any advice on this my chance?

Comment: I could be wrong, but they probably don't care much whether or not you use their document class during the review stage of submission. Especially if you might end up submitting to another journal later, I would just use whatever is most convenient. Once it's accepted, then my attitude varies by whether the journal is open access or commercial. I consider it the job of a commercial publisher to do the hard work when it comes to typesetting. For an open access journal with fewer resources, I try to do what I can to make it easy for them and follow their guidelines.

Comment: many journals that accept latex manuscripts do not use latex in production at all so _any_  time spent by the author tweaking the layout is wasted and just makes it more likely the conversion to the journal production format breaks and delays publication. (I do not know if that is the case here, but it would not surprise me)

Comment: thank you for your comments @DavidCarlisle. If they do not use latex in production. What do they use then?

Comment: thank you for your answer @frabjous. It's not easy to know what is the rule. If I do it the quick way and it gets reject, I tend to tell myself "I should have spend more time on the layout"...

Comment: @ecjb various commercial proprietary systems, or InDesign or APP or ....

Comment: @ecjb seems like I made a good guess, starting from the link in your question I randomly browsed to an article and landed on https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpace.2022.876191/full that is available as html and pdf, neither made with latex, the PDF is made as I guessed above by APP

Comment: Ok thanks @DavidCarlisle. And what does APP stands for?

Comment: abortext advanced print publisher  (often known by its old name 3B2 (which didn't stand for anything as far as I know)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbortext_Advanced_Print_Publisher

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code provided in the Frontiers template:

```
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\begin{subfigure}
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{logo1.eps}
        \caption{This is Subfigure 1.}
        \label{fig:Subfigure 1}
    \end{minipage}  
   
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\setcounter{subfigure}{1}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{logo2.eps}
        \caption{This is Subfigure 2.}
        \label{fig:Subfigure 2}
    \end{minipage}

\setcounter{figure}{2}
\setcounter{subfigure}{-1}
    \caption{Enter the caption for your subfigure here. \textbf{(A)} This is the caption for Subfigure 1. \textbf{(B)} This is the caption for Subfigure 2.}
    \label{fig: subfigures}
\end{subfigure}
```